# In Ramda how to look at next value in an array, to remove values that repeat one after another

Tags: ramda.js

So I have the following array

```
[true,true,false,false,false,true,false,false,true,true].
```

How can I use ramda to make the array look as follows

```
[true,false,true,false,true]
```

Also if the data was instead

```
[{t: '2018-10/09', v:true},{t: '2018-10/08', v:true}, {t: '2018-10/07', v:false},{t: '2018-10/06', v:false},{t: '2018-10/05', v:false},{t: '2018-10/04', v:true},{t: '2018-10/03', v:false},{t: '2018-10/02', v:false},{t: '2018-10/01', v:true},{t: '2018-09/09', v:true}]
```

and I wanted to dropRepeats using v only, then I would use R.dropRepeats(bool.v) ? 
Also as a side note, I am using R.pipe to get the input and do the transformations on the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ramda happens to have a built-in function for that, [`dropRepeats`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#dropRepeats)

```js
const bools = [true,true,false,false,false,true,false,false,true,true]

console.log(R.dropRepeats(bools))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

#### Update

A comment asked how I would do this on a slightly more complex structure.  It would be much the same, using [`dropRepeatsWith`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#dropRepeatsWith) and [`eqProps`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#eqProps):

```js
const bools = [{t: '2018-10/09', v:true},{t: '2018-10/08', v:true}, {t: '2018-10/07', v:false},{t: '2018-10/06', v:false},{t: '2018-10/05', v:false},{t: '2018-10/04', v:true},{t: '2018-10/03', v:false},{t: '2018-10/02', v:false},{t: '2018-10/01', v:true},{t: '2018-09/09', v:true}]

console.log(R.dropRepeatsWith(R.eqProps('v'), bools))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nice! I wasn't even aware that function existed.

Comment: It's a big API!

Comment: Thank you very much...if the bools was  [{t: '2018-10/09', v:true},{t: '2018-10/08', v:true}, 
{t: '2018-10/07', v:false},{t: '2018-10/06', v:false},{t: '2018-10/05', v:false},{t: '2018-10/04', v:true},{t: '2018-10/03', v:false},{t: '2018-10/02', v:false},{t: '2018-10/01', v:true},{t: '2018-09/09', v:true}]...and I wanted to dropRepeats using v only, then I would use R.dropRepeats(bool.v) ?

Comment: @Apana: Updated to answer this version.   Note that your suggestion (`bool.v`) can't do anything, since `bool` isn't defined anywhere.

Comment: Thank you very much..you are a life saver:)...I actually had another property 'fqn' in the structure..i.e const bools = [{t: '2018-10/09', v:true, fqn: 'a1'},{t: '2018-10/08', v:true, fqn: 'a1'}, {t: '2018-10/07', v:false, fqn: 'a1'},{t: '2018-10/06', v:false, fqn: 'a2'},{t: '2018-10/05', v:false, fqn: 'a2'},{t: '2018-10/04', v:true, fqn: 'a2'},{t: '2018-10/03', v:false, fqn: 'a2'},{t: '2018-10/02', v:false, fqn: 'a3'},{t: '2018-10/01', v:true, fqn: 'a3'},{t: '2018-09/09', v:true, fqn: 'a3'}]....so I used r.dropRepeatsWith(r.eqProps('fqn') && r.eqProps('v') ) and it worked great.... thx!!

Comment: That should not work as written. `r.eqProps('fqn')` is a function, a truthy value, as is `r.eqProps('v')`, Doing `func1 && func2` will always return true.  You can combine them with a lambda: `(o1, o2) => r.eqProps('fqn', o1, o2) && r.eqProps('v', o1, o2)`, but it would probably be easier to use Ramda's [`both`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#both) function: `r.both(r.eqProps('fqn'), r.eqProps('v')`

Comment: @Scott Sauyet..just realized the && didn't work..thankyou for the solution with r.both!!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a solution using `groupWith`:

You use `groupWith` to group consecutive identical elements into sub arrays, then you use `head` in `map` to take the first element of each sub array.

```js
const prune = R.pipe(R.groupWith(R.equals), R.map(R.head));

console.log(
  prune([true,true,false,false,false,true,false,false,true,true]));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

Comment: I like this solution and would recommend it except that Ramda has the relevant function built-in, [`dropRepeats`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#dropRepeats)